# Решить уравнение методом Дихотомии

Tags: python

Решить уравнение с диапазоном (e^x)+(x^2)-2=0 [-4, -1,2] методом дихотомии

После написания программы Python не выдает ошибок и ответа соответственно. Что не так в моей программе? Буду благодарен если кто-то поможет мне ее править.

```
from math import *
from decimal import *


def f(value):
    return exp(value) + value**2 - 2


a, b, eps, x = -4, -1.2, float(input()), -4
f1 = f(a)
f2 = f(x)
while eps <= 0:
    print("Введите положительное значение точности", end=" ")
    eps = float(input())
if eps > 1:
    eps = 1/eps
dx = (b - a) * eps
while x <= b:
    x += dx
    if f1 * f2 < 0:
        print(Decimal(x - 0.5*dx), '\n')
        break
    f1 = f2
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А разве дихотомия - это не вот такое:

```
import math

def sign(x):
    return bool(x > 0) - bool(x < 0)

def f(value):
    return math.exp(value) + value**2 - 2

old = -4
new = -1.2

f_old = f(old)
f_new = f(new)

while True:
    tmp = (old + new) / 2
    f_tmp = f(tmp)

    if abs(tmp - old) < 0.0000001:
        break

    if sign(f_tmp) == sign(f_old):
        old, f_old = tmp, f_tmp
    else:
        new, f_new = tmp, f_tmp

print("x = ", (old + new) / 2)
```

Comment: Спасибо что продемонстрировали мне другой вид решения данного задания. Хотелось еще узнать что нужно изменить в этой программе чтобы можно было задать любой другой диапазон.

Comment: измените первоначальные значения `old` и `new`, но метод работает только если функция имеет лишь 1 решение в диапазоне `Хотелось еще узнать что нужно изменить в этой программе чтобы можно было задать любой другой диапазон.` - нет, не все так просто - данный способ работает только в случае, если существует в заданном диапазоне лишь 1 решение задачи, приведённая функция имеет 2 решения (но в заданном диапазоне только 1 значение)

Comment: Ясно понял спасибо что объяснили

Answer (score 1):

У вас `f2` не пересчитывается внутри цикла, оно вычисляется только один раз до начала цикла. В результате цикл просто доходит до конца отрезка, не находя нужного результата. Если я правильно понял, нужно вычислять `f2` внутри цикла после изменения `x`:

```
while x <= b:
    x += dx
    f2 = f(x) # <-- ПЕРЕСЧИТЫВАЕМ f2
    if f1 * f2 < 0:
        print(Decimal(x - 0.5*dx), '\n')
        break
    f1 = f2
```

В этом случае получается такой результат, если ввести `100000`:

```
-1.3159620000079581547680618314188905060291290283203125
```

Проверим ответ (`e` берётся из уже импортированного модуля `math`):

```
x = -1.3159620000079581547680618314188905060291290283203125
print((e**x)+(x**2)-2)
```

Вывод:

```
-2.7839407759522317e-05
```

Близко к нулю, с погрешностью именно на заданную точность. Если ещё уменьшить `eps`, ещё ближе к нулю будет, я проверял.